# RoR: Monitor Indexing Migration

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, database, indexing

I plan to index my 100 million row (ruby on rails) database on a couple of fields, and the problem is that I have no way of knowing the progress of these migrations.

Usually, if I am running a manual data migration, I will do a basic `i+=1;print("#{i},")` to keep track of how far along it is, and to make sure it is still working.

Does anyone know if there is a way to do something like this with my indexing migration so i can monitor its progress?

Answer (score 1):

You could fork and create the index in one process while outputting the progress information in the other. It would look something like this:

```
pid = fork {

  # do index creation here

}

child_pid = nil
begin
  child_pid = Process.waitpid(pid, Process::WNOHANG)

  # output progress info here

end while child_pid.nil?
```